# Fast modulo operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [calculating $a^b \!\mod c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculating-ab-mod-c)

I have a number of form:  $p^n + p$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n$ can be any large number, for example, say  $10^{12}$.

What is the generic algorithm to compute $(p^n + p) \pmod k$, where $k$ is a huge number say $k=1000000007$.

Thanks!

Comment: Since adding $p$ modulo $k$ is about as easy as any operation can be, perhaps the generic question is about exponentiating $p^n$ modulo $k$, a topic dealt with in previous questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [calculating $a^b$ mod $c$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26722/3111).  Also two more times since then, [Modular exponentiation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119374/3111) and [how to calculate $f^x$ using fast binary exponentiation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91849/3111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know (a+b)mod n = ((a mod n) + (b mod n)) mod n . 
So I guess addition here is not a problem.

The real question seems to be on $p^n$ mod k  where n is large. For that, have a look at [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) on wikipedia.

Comment: thank you , i will check it out.